# Better syntax to update nested objects on redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Given a reducer example like the following

```
_({
  expandAbility: (state, a: { which: string }) => ({
    ...state,
    report: state.report && {
      waitingForIt: false,
      content: state.report.content && {
        ...state.report.content,
        interaction: {
          expandAbilities: !state.report.content.interaction.expandAbilities.contains(a.which)
            ? state.report.content.interaction.expandAbilities.add(a.which)
            : state.report.content.interaction.expandAbilities.remove(a.which)
        }
      }
    }
  }),
})
```

(state type given below just for question context purposes)

```
const initialState = {
  report: undefined as
    | {
        waitingForIt?: boolean
        content?: {
          supportedFightIds: number[]
          deathCut: number
          reportInfo: any
          deathsFull: any
          deathsByPlayer: any
          deathsByAbility: any
          interaction: {
            expandAbilities: Set<string>
          }
        }
      }
    | undefined,
  error: undefined as Error | undefined
}
```

Is there any kind of trick or "flavor-of-the-moment" library which would allow me to write a reducer update operation like `expandAbility` in a shorter way? (besides maybe creating some `vars` to reference inner paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of immutable update utilities out there, check out some options at https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutable-update-utilities and see what would be the best fit for you.
For starters check out Immutability-helper or immer.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two things you could do to help simplify this. The first thing I like to do is move the logic out of the reducer and instead just pass in a value and say set `expandAbilities` to `action. expandAbilities`.

The second is actually something we do at work. We use immutableJS and wrote a single reducer that handles all of our state calls because you can give it a path of the parts of state that need to be updated and the value to update it with so we extracted that out and now it is easy to say `dispatch(actions.update({path: ['report', 'content', 'interaction', 'expandAbilities'], value: '123' }))`

You can even expand this so you can pass in a list of values that need to be updated and even preform validations around the data.